# Cassandra returns Unordered result set for numeric values

Tags: cassandra

I am new to No SQL and just started learning Cassandra, I have a following question to ask. I have created a simple table with one column to understand Cassandra partition and clustering and trying to query all the values after insertion.

My table structure

```
create table if not exists music_library(custno int,  primary key(custno))
```

I inserted following values in a sequential order

```
insert into music_library(custno) values (11) 
insert into music_library(custno) values (12) 
insert into music_library(custno) values (13) 
insert into music_library(custno) values (14)
```

then I was querying this table

```
select * from music_library
```

it returns values in the following order

```
13
11
14
12
```

but i was expecting

```
11
12
13
14
```

Why its behaving like that?

Answer (score 5):

I ran your exact statements and produced the same result.  But I also adjusted your query to run the `token` function, and this is what it produced:

```
aaron@cqlsh:stackoverflow> select custno,token(custno) from music_library;

 custno | system.token(custno)
--------+----------------------
     13 | -5034495173465742853
     11 | -4156302194539278891
     14 |  4279681877540623768
     12 |  8582886034424406875

(4 rows)
```

> Why its behaving like that?

Simply put, because Cassandra cannot order results by the values of the partition keys.

As your table has a single primary key of `custno`, your rows are partitioned by the hashed token value of `custno`, and written to the nodes responsible for those token ranges.  When you run an unbound query in Cassandra (query without a `WHERE` clause), the results are returned ordered by the hashed token values of their partition keys.

Using `ORDER BY` won't work here, either.  `ORDER BY` can only sort data *within* a partition, and even then only on clustering keys.  To get the `custno` values to order properly, you will need to find a new partition key, and then specify `custno` as a clustering key in an ascending direction.

**Edit 20190916 - follow-up clarifications**

> Does this tokenization will happen for all the columns?

No.  The partition keys are hashed into a token to determine their placement in the cluster (which node(s) they are written to).  Individual column values are written *within* a partition.

> How will I return the inserted number with the order?

You cannot alter the order of this table without changing the model.  Simply put, you'll have to find a way to organize the values you expect to return (with your query) together (find another partition key).  Exactly how that looks depends on your business/query requirements.

For example, let's say that I wanted to track which customers purchased specific music albums.  I might create a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customers_by_album (
  album TEXT,
  band TEXT,
  custno INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (album,custno))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (custno ASC);
```

After inserting some data, the following query returns results ordered by `custno`:

```
aaron@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT album,token(album),band,custno FROM
    customers_by_album WHERE album='Moving Pictures';

 album           | system.token(album) | band | custno
-----------------+---------------------+------+--------
 Moving Pictures | 7819329704333693835 | Rush |     11
 Moving Pictures | 7819329704333693835 | Rush |     12
 Moving Pictures | 7819329704333693835 | Rush |     13
 Moving Pictures | 7819329704333693835 | Rush |     14

(4 rows)
```

This works, because I am querying data by a partition (`album`), and then I am "clustering" on `custno` which leverages the on-disk sort order.  This is also the order the data was written to disk in, so Cassandra just reads it from the partition sequentially.

I wrote an article on this topic for DataStax a few years ago, and it's still quite relevant.  Give it a read if you get a chance: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order

Comment: Hi Araon, Thank you for the prompt response. If the order is determined by the token, then how will I return the inserted number with the order and also does this tokenized will happen for all the columns?

Comment: @senthil Edit made.

Comment: It's never enough to fully know Cassandra, years go by, and I keep discovering its new  "tricks". Until now, I was totally sure we can order by partition key.